# Javascript running but having no effect in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I have a submit action that takes a while to process, so have added an onclick event to the submit button, which does a few things, e.g. changes button colour by adding/removing css classes, inserts an  spinner icon, to alert the user that something is happening (don't keep clicking!)
While this works very well on Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc., on Safari the changes are having not effect.

So, I can see in dev tools that the changes are being made in the mark-up (classes switched,  element added) but nothing visibly changes on the page. More specifically, testing in Mojave I can see the added  but not the colour change, testing in Catalina no changes are visible on page.

```js
function confirmUnlink(element, supplierIndex) {
  const cancelButton = document.querySelector("button.cancel-unlink");
  element.classList.remove("red");
  element.classList.add("grey");
  element.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<i class="spinner"></i>');
  element.disabled = "true";
  cancelButton.disabled = "true";
  document.querySelector('#supplier-unlink-index').value = supplierIndex;
  document.querySelector("#selectaccount-form").submit();
}
```

```html
<button type="button" id="confirm-@supplier.SupplierIndex" onclick="confirmUnlink(this, '@supplier.SupplierIndex')" name="unlinkSupplierIndex" value="@supplier.SupplierIndex" class="columns five confirm-unlink red">@Model.EditableContent.UnlinkConfirmButtonText</button>
<button type="button" id="cancel-@supplier.SupplierIndex" onclick="cancelUnlink('@supplier.SupplierIndex')" class="columns five offset-by-two cancel-unlink">@Model.EditableContent.UnlinkCancelButtonText</button>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the templating with actual text and make a [mcve]

Comment: problem is redraw does not happen before submit is fired so if page is navigating it probably does not run.